# Android memory limit test issue?

Tags: java, c#, android, memory, xamarin.android

I've read somewhere that a single Android app has a limit of 16MB memory (may be higher for some devices). So it looks like that's true when it comes to loading some data (such as images) from network.

On my virtual device (Visual Studio Emulator for Android), the memory limit is about 46MB. I guess that because the number of images I can load before throwing the OutOfMemoryException is 46 images (each image has size of about 1MB).

At first I thought the memory might exceed only when the images are shown on the ImageViews (which are wrapped in items of ListView or RecyclerView). However the exception is still thrown (I can see it in the output window) no matter the loaded images are shown or not.

So I would like to reproduce the OutOfMemoryException by such as loading a local list of some type, such as `List<int>` with the number of items being about 13 000 000 (that should exceed 46MB). However the exception is not thrown. I even tried increasing the number of items to 130 000 000 and still the same, not any exception is thrown. Here is the code:

```
//the local list is declared inside my main Activity class
List<int> _ints = new List<int>();
for(var i = 0; i < 130000000; i++) {
    _ints.Add(i);
}
```

So looks like I understand the cause of OutOfMemoryException in a wrong way. Could you explain this to me or if possible give me some example code or suggestion to reproduce the OutOfMemoryException but don't relate to download anything from network, I mean keeping it as simplest as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OutOfMemoryException` you are getting comes from the Java side. You cannot reproduce it by using only C# objects.

You need to allocate big Java objects. It doesn't work with a lot of small objects because there is a limit to how many Java objects can be referenced from C# code.

`Android.Graphics.Bitmap` is a good candidate :

```
List<Bitmap> _ints = new List<Bitmap>();
for (var i = 0; i < 130000000; i++)
{
    _ints.Add(Bitmap.CreateBitmap(1000, 1000, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888));
}
```

The resulting Java exception (wrapped in a mono exception) :

```
Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4000012 byte allocation with 219956 free bytes and 214KB until OOM
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0
    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfomethod, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00082] in <a043032cf94a485190047a14918b9f60>:0
    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00019] in <a043032cf94a485190047a14918b9f60>:0
    at Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, Android.Graphics.Bitmap+Config config) [0x0005e] in <3140893b79904cefbb68181cd89998e0>:0
    at SomeActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00024] in <efd0cb86bcd8422d9a46a0a8a1804b4d>:0
    at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <71c3e52f1b484794bca1cdfb1b8b1fdb>:0
    at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:46337ec2-c41a-4805-8728-4ab907d01a03 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
    --- End of managed Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError stack trace ---
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4000012 byte allocation with 219956 free bytes and 214KB until OOM
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789)
      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:756)
      at md53b9888b0c3fe89a24cb980ab2ea2a8a2.SomeActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
      at md53b9888b0c3fe89a24cb980ab2ea2a8a2.someActivity.onCreate(SomeActivity.java:32)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
```

Edit : With Xamarin the memory issues are more complicated because there are 2 garbage collectors, and some objects like bitmaps exist in both.

This is explained in the Xamarin [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection), specially the chapter [Helping the GC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#Helping_the_GC)

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me, this looks like the best answer here, so I'll accept it soon. Thank you :). BTW, my actual problem is dealing with loading a lot of images. However I don't need to show them all. Currently the problem is after showing enough images (by scrolling through the list), the next images (by continuing scolling) are not shown (I doubt that the memory is full). I've not tried using an Image loader library because I want to try solving this myself first to help understand the issue better. If u have some more suggestion on this solution, I'll really appreciate it :)

Comment: added links to the xamarin documentation. By the way, where exactly does the exception happen ? Are you sure it is in the bitmap allocation ?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but at the position of the scrolling where the images start not showing, I can see a message in the output saying something like `OutOfMemoryException`. But it's strange that after trying debugging the heap memory, the images start not showing at significantly different points (one point is about 123MB while the other is about 85MB). So it really confuses me about this, the threads (loading the images) seem to run fine (exit code = 0) but actually the images are not loaded (I use async/await). So it starts making me think that the issue may not be memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void OOMTest() throws Exception {
    int count = 20;
    System.out.println("\n=================> started..\n");
    for (int itrator = 1; itrator < 100; itrator++) {
        System.out.println("Iteration " + itrator + " Free Mem: "
                + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        int[] memoryFillIntVar = new int[count];
        count = count * 5;
        System.out.println("\nRequired Memory for next loop: " + count);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however more explanation added should be better. Anyway I would like to give you 1 vote-up. This is still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the heap size an app has, it varies from phone to phone. It is set from the manufacturer and the minimum usually is 16MB. You can force to use a larger heap in your app by marking it in the Android Manifest but this should be used as last resort since it will cause the system to kill other apps that are in background in order to gain free memory.

In your case, note that even if an image is not shown it could be still in the app memory if another object is holding a reference to it. Image loading and management in Android it's usually problematic due to memory constraints of the heap. To overcome this issue Facebook wrote its own image loading library [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that uses a different heap to load the memory avoiding to use space used by other objects in the app. If you deal with a lot images consider introduce it in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about using Fresco, I've not even tried using some image loader library (that should be my last resort). Also I'm programming with Xamarin, so I'm not sure if there is a wrapper of Fresco in Xamarin. I've known of another image loader library such as Glide which is available in Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

The size that an image take in memory is not 1MB, The actual size that an image take in memory can be counted as:

Lets assume you have a image `2000x1250`. It needs `4x2000x1250` bytes of memory. 
Each pixel has a part of red, green, blue and alpha channel information.

So the actual size that would take in memory would be something like `4x2000x1250=10000000 Byte -> 9.5MB`

The best way to load the images is using a library, Libraries takes good care of recycling the bitmaps and loading the images, caching them etc.

Here is the collecting of my favorite ones, you can try and use whichever suits your needs. I always prefer the first one.

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

Comment: Yes, you're right about the size of images loaded in memory. Your suggestions about image loader libraries are also helpful (although someone has suggested one of them), anyway thank you for your answer.